# How to display row number of List View

Tags: android

I have a list view which has three text view (id, name, score). I am displaying name and score from database and I want to show the id as increasing number(1, 2, 3, 4. ).
How can I do this?

I can also display id form database but the problem is I am displaying name and score with score in decreasing order (ORDER by DESC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you can set the ID in your view directly to (position + 1). From this point of view your 'ID' in fact is a counter.

Comment: how to set id to (position + 1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you understand right.
how can I set id to (position + 1). To populate name and score I am Using 
String[] from = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_SCORE};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.score};
  
SimpleCursorAdapter scores = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.score_row, c, from, to);
  
setListAdapter(scores); 

now how can I make my view R.id.row_id as a counter

Comment: I would say you will have to extend the SimpleCursorAdapter - then you can override the bindView method, let the super class do most of the work for you (for the key and the score) and then set your counter based on cursor position you can get by calling cursor.getPosition(). Resources: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#bindView%28android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getPosition%28%29

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the answer. It definitely solved a similar problem I was facing. Here is a detailed example of what I did:

1. I have a ListView where each row is a RelativeLayout. The RelativeLayout contains a TextView with ID 'serial_no' which is supposed to contain the row number that I want to display
2. I extended the SimpleCursorAdapter as follows:

   ```
   public class CustomCursoAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

       public CustomCursoAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
               String[] from, int[] to) {
           super(context, layout, c, from, to);
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }

       @Override
       public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
       {
               int temp =cursor.getPosition()+1;
               RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view;
               TextView tv = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.serial_no);
               tv.setText(""+temp);
           super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In my Activity class instead of calling the SimpleCursorAdapter, I now call CustomCursorAdapter. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code and display in TextView or append with list Text.

```
cursor.getPosition()+1;
```